# What is the point of the following set of instructions in x86 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

I'm looking at some x86-64 assembly instructions, and these three lines puzzle me:

```
add    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
cmp    %eax,0x0(%rbp)
je     400f36 <func>
```

From what I understand, line 1 sets %eax to the value of %rbp - 4, then line 2 compares %eax's new value to $rbp and sets flags. The third line will jump if they are equal, but how could they ever be equal in this scenario?

Comment: `()` is memory indirection. That is doing `if ((eax += *(rbp-4)) == *rbp) func()'`

Comment: In other words: Line 1 sets EAX to the value stored at the memory address  `[RBP-4]`, then compares that to the value stored at the memory address `[RBP]`, and then, depending on equality, jumps to <func> or not. In other words, RBP contains a memory address (probably somewhere on the stack) and the code, via EAX, compares two values at consecutive DWORD addresses.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis and OP: first instruction is `add`, not `mov`. I.e. `eax` is added with the new value from memory, not set to it.

Comment: @Ped7g: Yes, indeed.